# Wicket PagingNavigator simulate onClick to go to a page

Tags: navigation, wicket, paging

I have a wicket PagingNavigator that works like a charm but I'm wondering how I can force the navigator to go to a particular page.  I have the typical First < 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 > Last nav links, but if I know there are other pages not visible (e.g. page 13) can I force the navigator to redirect to that page?  I've seen a lot of nice examples on creating the basic navigator and even customizing the with CSS, but nothing to describe the moving to some random page.

Answer (score 0):

```
pagingNavigator.getPageable().setCurrentPage(13);
```